# How can setup.py reference other files in the source repo?

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm having trouble getting a python package to build with `python -m build .`.  `setup.py` fails on:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements/requirements.txt'
```

It's caused by the fact that `build` is copying files to a temporary directory first.  But it's only copying the `source/`, `README.md`, `setup.py`, `setup.cfg`.  It's not copying `requirements/`.

---

For complex reasons my setup.py needs to reference other files at the root of the source repo - a directory containing multiple requirements.txt files.  *It's not really worth discussing why it needs to be structured this way, I've already been through that long debate with colleagues.*

This works fine when we install the package through `pip install -e .` or as a git dependency `git+ssh://...` but fails when building before we push to a pypi repo.

```
setup.cfg
setup.py
source/
source/my_package/
requirements/
requirements/requirements.txt
requirements/some-other-requirements.txt
```

setup.py references this directory before calling `setup()`.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages


requirements_dir = Path("requirements")


# This is the line that fails:
with (requirements_dir / "requirements.txt").open() as f:
    install_requires = list(f)


setup(
    packages=find_namespace_packages(where="source", include=["acme_corp.*"], exclude=["tests", "tests.*"]),
    package_dir={"": "source"},
    install_requires=install_requires,
    extras_require=optional_packages,
)
```

Comment: is that [this build](https://github.com/pypa/build/) ?

Comment: @2e0byo It's whatever you get when you type `pip3 install build` so I guess so.

Comment: Have you tried the [``build`` with ``--no-isolation``](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#python--m-build-optional-arguments)?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, that doesn't prevent the copying behaviour apparently.  I suspect it only controls the creation of a fresh virtual environment to protect from `setup.py` modifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`build` does the correct job here. After building the source dist, it checks whether the built result can be actually installed. And without including the files under `requirements` into the source dist, the source dist can not be installed and is thus unusable. Try it out:

```
$ python -m build --sdist  # builds fine, but the tar is broken:
$ cd dist
$ tar tf pkg-0.0.1.tar.gz | grep requirements  # will be empty
$ pip wheel pkg-0.0.1.tar.gz  # will fail
Processing ./pkg-0.0.1.tar.gz
  File was already downloaded 
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command:
   ...
  Complete output (9 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-req-build-wfzz27_k/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
      with (requirements_dir / "requirements.txt").open() as f:
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1252, in open
      return io.open(self, mode, buffering, encoding, errors, newline,
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1120, in _opener
      return self._accessor.open(self, flags, mode)
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-build-wfzz27_k/requirements/requirements.txt'
```

To fix, write a `MANIFEST.in` alongside the `setup.py` that includes `requirements` directory in the source dist. Example file contents:

```
graft requirements
```

Building a source dist should work now; you can additionally verify that the sdist now contains all files to install from:

```
$ tar tf dist/pkg-0.0.1.tar.gz | grep requirements
pkg-0.0.1/requirements/
pkg-0.0.1/requirements/requirements.txt
...
```

This only concerns the source dist, as the wheel is built on host (your machine) already and does not contain a setup script anymore. Wheel building will also ignore the `MANIFEST.in` file.

Comment: I guess this can be answered by the devs only :-) Maybe they imply that passing `--sdist` means you know what you're doing - after all, building a wheel may be time consuming and you want to avoid that explicitly by passing `--sdist`. Or maybe the answer is just that `build` is a relatively new project, so the check is to be implemented yet, who knows.

Comment: Yeah I think the time consuming part may be the issue.  If setup requires binaries to be built then the check isn't meaningful without doing so.  Depending on the project that could be a big overhead (pandas, cryptography).